# How do I remove SitePages/Home.aspx or Forms/AllItems.aspx correctly for ClientContext?

Tags: c#, winforms, sharepoint, csom

I am using CSOM to connect to SharePoint and load files from `Document Libraries`. My problem is when I create `ClientContext` object with the full URL that ends with `Forms/AllItems.aspx` or `SitePages/Home.aspx` or other bits, it will throw invalid URL exception.

For example, this will work:

`ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/Extranet/Test%20AutoAppraisal");`

And this will not work:

`ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/Extranet/Test%20AutoAppraisal/SitePages/Home.aspx");`

Is there a safe way to trim SharePoint URL similar to this new Microsoft Flow feature ([Automatic trimming of SharePoint URLs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/business-applications-release-notes/april18/microsoft-flow/automatic-sharepoint-url-trimming))?

My current solution, removing segment by segment until the `Uri` is valid, but this is time consuming for client experience.

```
private static Uri TryResolvingUrl(Uri path)
{
    string host = null;
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(path)
            {
                Credentials = _credential,
                RequestTimeout = -1
            };

            ctx.Load(ctx.Web, web => web.ServerRelativeUrl);
            ctx.ExecuteQueryRetry();
            return path;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            if (host == null)
            {
                host = path.Scheme + "://" + path.Authority;
            }

            if (path.Segments.Length == 1)
            {
                throw e; // we wont be able to use this url!
            }

            string newUrl = host;
            for (int i = 0; i < path.Segments.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                newUrl += path.Segments[i];
            }

            path = new Uri(newUrl.Unescape());
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you use regex or substring to do that?

Comment: @Deleted I can probably use that for short URLs, but it's difficult for the following url `https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/Extranet/Test%20AutoAppraisal/Account%20Managemenet%20Archive/Forms/AllItems.aspx?viewpath=%2FExtranet%2FTest%20AutoAppraisal%2FAccount%20Managemenet%20Archive%2FForms%2FAllItems.aspx`

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippet for your reference.

```
string siteUrl = "https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/Extranet/Test%20AutoAppraisal/Account%20Managemenet%20Archive/Forms/AllItems.aspx";       
var urlArray = siteUrl.Split('/');
siteUrl = urlArray[0]+"//"+urlArray[2]+"/"+urlArray[3]+"/"+urlArray[4];

using (ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(siteUrl))
{   

}
```

Comment: This is not safe for some URLs that contain `/sites/`